# Control "Tab key" with External Keyboard in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uitextfield

I have a screen with 3-4 textfields. One of textfield show alert when try to edit.

But when I try to edit other textfield & press **Tab key via external keyboard** then that alert will always show.

**MY code**

```
 func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing (_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

        if  textField == txt_a {

            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Custom TextField", message: "Do your custom work here", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            //self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

                return false
            }
        return true
    }
```

**So, How can I control/detect **Tab Key** ?

Thank you,